# How to install remote dependencies using MavenSession?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, maven-plugin, mojo

How can I install remote dependencies using MavenSession in a Maven plugin that I am working on?

I wasn't able to try because of the poor documentation of maven. I am new to maven so I don't know how things work here.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "install remote dependencies"? Usually, these dependencies come from some Maven repository. Then you can add that repository and declare the necessary dependencies in the POM.

Comment: Hi [J Fabian Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927493/j-fabian-meier), in my maven plugin goal, I need to add dependencies that are on a remote repository (Nexus repo) programmatically. However, I don't want to add them using the MavenProject, instead I want to use a MavenSession.

Comment: Are you writing a maven plugin? But the deps of a plugin are automatically downloaded by the core ... so there is no need to do that manually in your plugin? .... There seemed to be some misunderstandings how a plugin works...

Comment: @KevinNammour Why not just add them as dependency to your plugin project?

Comment: Hi [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) and [J Fabian Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927493/j-fabian-meier) the thing is that in my plugin, I need to resolve dependencies at runtime while executing the plugin, providing the groupid and artifactid

Comment: Where do these groupIds and artifactIds come from? Does the user of the plugin specify them in the `<configuration>` in the POM?